# why doesn't d3.scale Quantize generate discrete values over my continuous range

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I tried to use `d3.scaleQuantize()` to create a scale to outputs a number of discrete quantities defined by the range. Below is my code.

```
var d3 = require("d3")

var domain = ["a", "b","c","d"]
var color = d3.scaleQuantize()
    .domain(domain)
    .range([1,1000]);
domain.forEach(function(d){
    console.log(`${d} = ${color(d)}`);
});
```

The output of above code is as below:

```
"a = 1000"
"b = 1000"
"c = 1000"
"d = 1000"
```

I expect each element in the domain array should be scaled to the range of [1,1000]. Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Quantize scales are similar to linear scales, except they use a discrete rather than continuous range. The continuous input domain is divided into uniform segments based on the number of values in (i.e., the cardinality of) the output range.

You misunderstood quantize scale in d3. D3's quantize scale requires a *continuous domain input*, but in your case, your input is discrete. With quantize scale, the input is essentially divided into "buckets" depending on the number of values in the range array, again, because your domain is discrete, it can't correctly divide up your input array. To achieve what you need, use [Ordinal Scale](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#ordinal-scales)

Comment: In order to use ordinal scale, should I need to convert the range to be discrete as well?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: the domain array should be scaled among the range [0, 1000]

Comment: Ok, so if you use ordinal scale, then the last 2 elements in your domain (`c` and `d`) will just wrap around and map to the first and last elements in the range (`0`, and `1000`). Just change `scaleQuantize` to `scaleOrdinal`